# How do I correctly return context from a gnuwin32 grep (grep in windows cmd)?

Tags: windows, command-line, grep, cmd.exe, context

I want to return a line of context after the string I'm searching for as per 
grep --help

```
Context control:
  -B, --before-context=NUM  print NUM lines of leading context
  -A, --after-context=NUM   print NUM lines of trailing context
  -C, --context=NUM         print NUM lines of output context
```

However,

```
  grep -a1 string1 file.txt-
```

gives me context before AND after (same with b1)

```
  grep -a 1 string1 file.txt
```

searches for "1" in the file "string1"

and, just to make things weirder,

```
  grep -c1 string1 file.txt
```

gives me nothing at all

thank you in advance to anyone who can help :)

Comment: Are you using capitals for your `-A1` or lower case as your question has?  `-a` and `-A` are different flags after all, I would have thought lower case would always search for 1 in a file called `string1`

Comment: fantastic. Sometimes it's the simple things :)

Comment: I wonder why a1 works as a substitute for C 1 at all though...

Comment: Maybe 'cause Windows, unlike most *nixes, is case insensitive. I thought that was only a file system thing but apparently it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Please not that for GNU utilities (and in general), casing of the command line options used matter. Try

> `grep -C1 string1 file.txt`

instead. Note the capital 'C'!

BTW, the '`-c`' flag means *count*. Instead of showing all individual occurrences it just shows the total number of lines the string occurs on in your file(s).